# Draw Bar chart from the given excel data in the perl

Tags: perl, excel, charts

Draw Bar chart from the given excel data in the perl
Excel data : it changes dynamically every week. I wanted to automata it.

===============================

Below is the program :

- I have sample data in the Excel. The data can the name and marks obtained by the student in each subject.
- I want to draw excel chart for it.

  ```
  #!/usr/local/bin/perl
    print "Content-type: text/html\n\n"; 
    use strict; 
    use Win32::OLE;
    use Win32::OLE::Const 'Microsoft Excel';
    use Spreadsheet::ParseExcel; 
    use Spreadsheet::ParseExcel::SaveParser;

   my $parser   = new Spreadsheet::ParseExcel::SaveParser;
       my $workbook = $parser->Parse('Nilu.xls');

   my $worksheet1 = $workbook->worksheet('Worksheet1'); 
   $worksheet1->activate();

  my ( $row_min, $row_max ) = $worksheet1->row_range(); 
  my ( $col_min, $col_max ) = $worksheet1->col_range(); 

  print "row min:$row_min row_max:$row_max col_max:$col_max\n\n";

      my $worksheet2 = my $parser->add_worksheet( 'Worksheet2' );

  #$parser->add_worksheet( 'Worksheet2' );
  ```

  $worksheet2->activate();

  ```
  # Create a new chart object. In this case an embedded chart.
  my $chart1 = $workbook->add_chart( type => 'column', embedded => 1 );


  # Configure the first series.
  ```

  $chart1->add_series(
        name       => '=Sheet1!$B$1',
       categories => "=Sheet1!\$A\$2:\$A:$row_max",
         values     => "=Sheet1!\$B\$2:\$B:$row_max",
     );

  ```
  # Set an Excel chart style. Blue colors with white outline and shadow.
  $chart1->set_style( 11 );

  # Insert the chart into the worksheet (with an offset).
  $worksheet2->insert_chart( 'F2', $chart1, 25, 10 );

   # Write over the existing file or write a new file.
  $parser -> SaveAs('Nilu1.xls');
  ```

Comment: -1: No question, no visible effort. Please see [how to ask questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: I have again updated the information with the code...Kindly advice..

Answer (score 0):

You may use Spreadsheet::ParseExcel for parsing your Excel sheets (or export them as CSV data and then use Text::CSV_XS) and e.g. the Chart module for drawing the bar chart.

To give a more precise answer I would need further information, particularly:

- sample input data
- a sample chart
- And what exactly do you mean by "perl Excel data"?

Comment: Fany : I have again updated my question with the code above...Kindly advice the way to resolve it..

Answer (score 0):

Here is an [example of drawing a bar chart](http://search.cpan.org/~jmcnamara/Excel-Writer-XLSX/lib/Excel/Writer/XLSX/Examples.pm#Example%3a_chart_bar.pl) in Excel with Perl.

It isn't easy to update an existing file that contains charts with Perl (apart from using Win32::OLE on Windows) so I would recommend generating the Excel workbook each week.

Comment: jmcnamara ...thanks for your update. The link you provide was really helpful but I would like to know the way to create the chart from the dynamic data in the excel.....because every week I will be having new excel sheets where..Max Column range is known but Max Row range is unknown....